# React-native Firebase Push Notifications not works in iOS on development and release modes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apple-push-notifications, react-native-firebase

React-native firebase push notifications works fine in debug mode on iOS physical devices. But when i check on development or release modes it's not working.please help, why it's not working and i used APNs Authentication Key not APNs Certificates for notifications.

And also Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles of apple developer accounts which things or setup need to be verify and check.

`"@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.3.2",

"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.3.2",`